# Type checking fails with optional value in Swift

Tags: swift, typechecking

When I have an optional value of a class which conforms to a protocol, the type checking doesn't work as expected. E.g.:

```
import Foundation

protocol MyProtocol { }

class MyClass: MyProtocol { }

let myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
let myClassType = type(of: myClass)

print("myClassType is MyClass.Type: \(myClassType is MyClass.Type)")
print("myClassType is MyProtocol.Type: \(myClassType is MyProtocol.Type)")

let myClassOpt: MyClass? = MyClass()
let myClassTypeOpt = type(of: myClassOpt)

print("myClassTypeOpt is MyClass?.Type: \(myClassTypeOpt is MyClass?.Type)")
print("myClassTypeOpt is MyProtocol?.Type: \(myClassTypeOpt is MyProtocol?.Type)")
```

Output:

myClassType is MyClass.Type: true

myClassType is MyProtocol.Type: true

myClassTypeOpt is MyClass?.Type: true

myClassTypeOpt is MyProtocol?.Type: false

The expected value of last type checking is true, but got false.

Is there another way to check the type in this case?

Comment: When you say "another way to check the type," in order to do what? What would the next block of code look like if this did work the way you're thinking? This is almost certainly better solved another way.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `type(of: myClassOpt)` is not creating a variable of that type. Rather, it returns a string identifying the type of `myClassOpt`. Since you have declared `myClassOpt` as type `MyClass?`, the result is a string saying something like `Optional<MyClass>`.

So yes, when you run `myClassTypeOpt is MyProtocol?.Type`, the result is False.

Comment: So it's impossible to check the type of optional values?

Comment: Best way to check the type of an optional is with an `if let` or `guard let else` configuration. In this case, `if let mine = myClassOpt as? MyClass {...`. This is how I handle arguments of type `Any?`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using an `optional` to check its type, you can use `if-let` to first `unwrap` the `optional` value and then checking its type, i.e.

```
let myClassOpt: MyClass? = MyClass()

if let myClassOpt = myClassOpt {
    let myClassTypeOpt = type(of: myClassOpt)
    print("myClassTypeOpt is MyClass.Type: \(myClassTypeOpt is MyClass.Type)") //true
    print("myClassTypeOpt is MyProtocol.Type: \(myClassTypeOpt is MyProtocol.Type)") //true
}
```